# Use a White sheet or aluminum sheet during sunbathing to maximize uvb?

Tags: radiation

I'm trying to find a way to maximize my UVB exposure for Vitamin D production for the least amount of time as I have type 4 or 5 skin.

I've been lying on a white fleece sheet with these silver coloured car shades. So basically these sheets would be like using aluminum foil.

I lie on these sheets and my arms feel a burning sensation (later on) after 20 min exposure.

I've been looking at albedos and now I'm unsure.

So should I continue to use the "aluminum" or should I ditch the foil and lie on the plain white sheet instead? The white sheet mimics snow conditions.

Which material would maximize UVB refectance onto my skin?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is not about recommending medical treatments.

Comment: Don't you need like 10 minutes of sun exposure to get your daily requirements of Vitamin D?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero The question can be interpreted on a way that only the physical part is asked, without any medical skills (although it is doubtful even in this case that it is ontopic).

Comment: @peterh http://www.skincancer.org/prevention/uva-and-uvb

Comment: Wow so unhelpful.  Does a white sheet or a sheet of aluminum reflect more UV? Simple question.

Comment: I saw this person make a solar oven using foil. She wasn't using a white  sheet in her solar oven.  So I know foil maximizes infrared. But I'm asking about UVB.

Comment: In another stack exchange thread, someone wrote that snow had an albedo of like 0.8 and aluminum 0.65. So white sheet wins in reflectance?

Comment: And Kyle, not everyone's white.

Answer (score 1):

I copied the following off corona-renderer.com.

---

I gathered this small list from various sources, so there may be few duplicates or even contradictions. But i think it's nice to have such list handy. Feel free to contribute to this list.

ALBEDO:

New asphalt, 0.04 - 0.05
Black acrylic paint, 0.05
Aged asphalt, 0.1 - 0.12
Conifer Forest, 0.08 - 0.15
Bare soil, 0.17
Deciduous trees, 0.15 - 0.18
"White" asphalt shingle, 0.2
Green grass, 0.25
Aged concrete, 0.2 - 0.3
Desert sand, 0.4
New concrete (traditional), 0.4 - 0.55
Ocean ice, 0.5 - 0.7
New concrete with white portland cement, 0.7 - 0.8
White acrylic paint, 0.8
Fresh snow, 0.8 - 0.9
Water, 0.03 - 1.0

Old/melting snow  0.40 - 0.80
Tundra 0.2

Soil (Dark/Wet) 0.05 
Soil (Light/Grey) 0.4
Sand 0.15 - 0.45
Ice (Sea) 0.3 - 0.45
Ice (Glacier) 0.2 - 0.4

white asphalt shingle - 0.2
galvanized steel - 0.24
terra cota tile - 0.28
tar & gravel - 0.33

magnesium oxide - 0.96 [D]
alabaster - 0.92 [D]
polished silver - 0.88-0.93 (S)
white gypsum - 0.85 [D]
fresh snow - 0.75-0.78 [M]
mirror - 0.72-0.85 (S)
matte silver - 0.7 [D-S]
polished aluminum - 0.65-0.75 (S)
polished chrome - 0.6-0.7 (S)
matte aluminum - 0.55-0.6 [D-S]
white paper sheet - 0.6-0.7 [D-S]
melting snow (clean) - 0.6-0.62 [M]
matte chrome - 0.5 [D-S]
plaster - 0.4-0.45 [D]
natural silk fabric - 0.35-0.55 [M]
batten (fresh wood) - 0.35-0.42 [D-S]
face skin - 0.25-0.35 [M]
white dry sand - 0.24-0.32 [D]
yellow clay - 0.16 [D]
batten (old, weathered) 0.12-0.16 [D-S]
white wet sand - 0,11-0.2 [D]
dry asphalt - 0.1-0.18 [M]
black soil (dry) - 0.07-0.08 [D]
wet asphalt - 0.06-0.08 [D-S]
summer foliage - 0.09-0.12 [D-S]
conifer - 0.08-0.12 [D & D-S]
autumn foliage - 0.15-0.3 [D-S]
black soil (wet) - 0.02-0.05 [D-S]
black velvet - 0.01-0.03 [D]

D - diffuse
S - specular
M - mixed

---

Since no one else answered, I'm going to say that foil and a white sheet have comparable albedos. A white piece of paper is around 0.7 and so is polished aluminum.

Answer (score 0):

I'm modifying my answer. The silver side of sunscreens are often a type of Mylar, which would have an albedo of about 0.85.

Besides, why would manufacturers manufacture silver sun screens? If the colour white had better reflectivity, then the sun shades would be white. Therefore, I get more UVB reflected back to me using sun shades.